# stitchSchema returns null

Tags: next.js, graphql, apollo-server

I have stitched two schemas together and run on localhost to query it. But the query returns null for the data in the second schema and I am not sure why.

I have the following code to stitch to remote schemas together and run a localhost graphql server to serve it. It should add the linked data from the second schema under cmsMetaData in the main Product data. But cmsMetaData is null.

```
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-micro';
import { ApolloServerPluginInlineTraceDisabled, ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault } from "apollo-server-core";
import { stitchSchemas } from '@graphql-tools/stitch';
import { delegateToSchema } from '@graphql-tools/delegate';
import { RenameTypes, RenameRootFields } from '@graphql-tools/wrap';

import createRemoteSchema from '../../utils/createRemoteExecutor';

// Configuration for Next.js API Routes
export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    },
};

// Export as a Next.js API Route
export default async (req, res) => {
    
    // Setup subschema configurations
    const productsSubschema = await createRemoteSchema({
        url: 'https://schema1.com/graphql/'
    });
    
    const cmsSubschema = await createRemoteSchema({
        url: 'https://schema2.com/graphql/',
        transforms: [
            new RenameRootFields(
                (operationName, fieldName, fieldConfig) => `strapi_${fieldName}`,
            ),
            new RenameTypes((name) => `Strapi_${name}`),
        ],
    });
    
    // Build the combined schema and set up the extended schema and resolver
    const schema = stitchSchemas({
        subschemas: [productsSubschema, cmsSubschema],
        typeDefs: `
        extend type Product {
            cmsMetaData: Strapi_Product
        }
        `,
        resolvers: {
            Product: {
                cmsMetaData: {
                    selectionSet: `{ id }`,
                    resolve(product, args, context, info) {
                        
                        // Get the data for the extended type from the subschema for Strapi
                        return delegateToSchema({
                            schema: cmsSubschema,
                            operation: 'query',
                            fieldName: 'strapi_product',
                            args: { where: { SaleorID: product.id } },
                            context,
                            info,
                        });
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    });

    // Set up the GraphQL server
    const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
        schema,
        plugins: [
            ApolloServerPluginInlineTraceDisabled(),
            ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault({ embed: true }),
        ],
    });
    await apolloServer.start();
    const apolloServerHandler = apolloServer.createHandler({
        path: '/api/graphql',
    });

    // Return the GraphQL endpoint
    return apolloServerHandler(req, res);
};
```

utils/createRemoteExecutor.js is:

```
import { introspectSchema, wrapSchema } from '@graphql-tools/wrap';
import { print } from 'graphql';

// Builds a remote schema executor function,
// customize any way that you need (auth, headers, etc).
// Expects to recieve an object with "document" and "variable" params,
// and asynchronously returns a JSON response from the remote.
export default async function createRemoteSchema({ url, ...filters }) {
    const executor = async ({ document, variables }) => {
        const query = print(document);
        const fetchResult = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                // We can also do Authentication here
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ query, variables }),
        });
        return fetchResult.json();
    };

    return wrapSchema({
        schema: await introspectSchema(executor),
        executor,
        ...filters,
    });
}
```

The query is:

```
products(first: 100, channel: "default-channel")
{
    edges
    {
        node
        {
            id
            name        
            cmsMetaData
            {
                Title
                SaleorID
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my api.tsx, which I generate using codegen.yaml, Product contains cmsMetaData as follows, which is of type Strapi_Product:

```
export type Product = Node & ObjectWithMetadata & {
    __typename?: 'Product';
    ... 
    cmsMetaData?: Maybe<Array<Maybe<Strapi_Product>>>;
    ...
}
```

Strapi_Product is as follows which contains Title, SaleorID etc.:

```
export type Strapi_Product = {
    __typename?: 'Strapi_Product';
    SaleorID?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
    Title?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
    createdAt?: Maybe<Scalars['Strapi_DateTime']>;
    publishedAt?: Maybe<Scalars['Strapi_DateTime']>;
    updatedAt?: Maybe<Scalars['Strapi_DateTime']>;
};
```

But the date in GraphQL shows null for cmsMetaData as null:

```
{
  "data": {
    "products": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "UHJvZHVjdDoxMjc=",
            "name": "52-00 Base Plate",
            "cmsMetaData": null
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "UHJvZHVjdDoxMjg=",
            "name": "52-01HD Weigh Module",
            "cmsMetaData": null
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems related to this [github](https://github.com/ardatan/graphql-tools/issues/1725) issue. Most of your code looks totally fine, so I guess it fetches the schema correctly. The `cmsMetaData` field is null because it did not find anything matching objects using the selection criteria. This unwanted behavior is in the transformation and/or the resolver.

A good starting point for debugging would be to remove the `RenameRootFields` mutation. Furthermore, this [example](https://graphql.wtf/episodes/12-graphql-remote-schema-stitching) looks like your use case, it is an excellent step-by-step guide.

I also rebuild your example from an example I found on the internet. You most probably have a typo in one of the field names, that caused a null value for me. Make sure A equals B in the code below. I am guessing the initial fieldName is "Product", so after the transformation, this does not equal "strapi_product" and returns a null value.

```
const cmsSubschema = await createRemoteSchema({
    url: 'https://schema2.com/graphql/',
    transforms: [
        new RenameRootFields(
            (_, fieldName) => `strapi_${fieldName}`,), // A
        new RenameTypes((name) => `Strapi_${name}`),
    ],
});

// Build the combined schema and set up the extended schema and resolver
const schema = stitchSchemas({
    subschemas: [productsSubschema, cmsSubschema],
    typeDefs: `
    extend type Product {
        cmsMetaData: Strapi_Product
    }
    `,
    resolvers: {
        Product: {
            cmsMetaData: {
                selectionSet: `{ id }`,
                resolve(product, args, context, info) {
                    
                    // Get the data for the extended type from the subschema for Strapi
                    return delegateToSchema({
                        schema: cmsSubschema,
                        operation: 'query',
                        fieldName: 'strapi_product', // B
                        args: { where: { SaleorID: product.id } },
                        context,
                        info,
                    });
                },
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: OK thanks a lot for comments, its useful to know that the method could be correct and could be some typo or similar. In the meantime we have used Stepzen to do the stitching which is working.

Comment: @LaurenceCope I am confident it is a typo / wrong fieldName somewhere, I recreated it from the example and implemented your transformations and resolver. Would you mind accepting the answer if you are satisfied?

Comment: I have not had the time to determine if this is the reason yet, some typo in my code. I have had an email that my bounty has expired, so I am not sure what happens with that now. I have not used bounties before. If it means its gone then thats really bad, I did not have any time to check its a solution, and it was even over the weekend when I dont monitor work emails.

Comment: Also, I dont think I can remove the RenameRootFields operation. Both Saleor and Strapi have a type called product, so it conflicts.

Comment: So nobody got the bounty points and they are gone ;-) You should vote or accept an answer as the best answer, if there is any ofcourse. This way people get rewarded points if they put in effort to give a good answer. And what i suggested was only about the field names, not the types.

Comment: But I cannot accept on answers without knowing if its correct! The overall summary was "its a typo". I have already spent weeks of time on the code and looked at typos. So its not a 5 minute job to implement that solution. I am grateful for the time put in, but honestly, Stackoverflow gave no time for me to look into it, and it was over the weekend so I did not even know! I could not avoid missing their deadline as I did not work on the weekend, they gave no time. Sorry about that. I lose the points too. When I look into it and fix it, I can then determine if its the solution.